# For what values of parameter linear transformation is bijective?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

We have a linear transformation $T$:

$T: R^3\to R^3$

$T(x)=(mx_1+x_2+x_3, x_1+mx_2+x_3, x_1+x_2+mx_3)$

For what values of $m$ the trasformation is bijective ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint** : Your transformation is linear with matrix
$$
A_T:=\begin{pmatrix}m&1&1\\1&m&1\\1&1&m\end{pmatrix},
$$
so the problem is to find the values of $m$ for which $A_T$ is invertible (you could find the values of $m$ for which $\text{det}A_T=0$ and those values will be the ones for which the transformation is *not* bijective).

Comment: For which $det A \ne 0$.

Comment: @JankoBracic Yeah I edited I think it's OK now?

Comment: @Guest I found that parameter m should not be -2 and 1, thus determinant of the matrix isn't zero so kerT is (0,0,0) from $R^3$. This I know, but what should I do with surjectivity of the linear transformation ?

Comment: @Guest Yes, it is ok. I have upvoted the answer.

Comment: @JohnG. A linear transformation is bijective if, and only if, its representative matrix is invertible. The injectivity comes from $\ker T=0$ and the surjectivity comes from the fact that the dimension of the $\text{Span}$ of the column-vectors of $A_T$ is $3$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @Guest Thank you very much

Comment: @JohnG. You're welcome.